# is Laravel Homestead essential?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'd like to setup and use `Laravel` as a PHP framework. I faced with `Homestead`.
I don't know what is this.
is this essential for Laravel and the projects that i make with it ?

Comment: Have you read the [Laravel Installation Documention](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation) and the [Homestead Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead)? All the info you need is there.

Comment: No, it's only an option. You may use `xampp` or whatever and in this case `Homestead` is a pre-built a custom Vagrant box when you use a virtual machine.

Comment: @bogdan : Yes. I've read. it didn't explain that it's essential or not.

Comment: If it doesn't say that it's essential then it means it's not :). In any case @TheAlpha summed it up well in his comment.

Comment: Thanks both. I got my answer :}

Comment: If you read between the lines, it is far beyond than essential.

Comment: @user2094178 : why ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sniping the answer here, just in case others have the same question:

Homestead is nothing more than a [Vagrant Environment](http://vagrantup.com)

What Vagrant does is spin up virtual servers on your local machine that you may then interact with as if they were remote servers. The idea behind this is two-fold:

1. Vagrant Environments can be tailored specifically to mirror - or come close to matching - the production environment on which your web application will be hosted.
2. Vagrant files can be version controlled so that team members working on the same project are guaranteed to be working in the same environment.

With all that said, all Homestead is is a Vagrant box that has a basic LEMP stack and a bunch of other server components configured for you out of the box that will enable you to quickly provision new sites and databases through a simple YAML configuration.

While it would certainly be easier to spin up a Laravel/Lumen installation for local development within a Homestead environment, you could really do it within any kind of virtual machine or locally installed HTTP server.

If you really wanted to, you could also used PHP's built-in server to quickly spin up a Laravel application as well by running `php artisan serve` in a Laravel 4 application, or `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` in Laravel 5.

But ultimately, no, Homestead is not a necessity. Only a nicety.